# Using dc.js without crossfilter

Tags: dc.js

They have been various discussions on how to use dc.js simply as graph library (eg. to draw a piechart, a barchart...) without needing crossfilter, for instance if you simply want to draw a single pie when the data is already a (label, value).

I didn't find any example of how to do that. Is this possible on the 2.0 branch? Will it work for every chart?

Comment: If you're only drawing a single chart, I'd suggest another library such as Vega or nvd3. Most of the value of dc.js is in the transitions and filtering between charts. While some effort was made a year ago to support straight data through `.data()`, this was only half competed; see https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584 for a list of charts which defeat the purpose by using the function internally.

Comment: The aim was to use the same framework, no matter for a simple pie or complex stuff that benefit from all the nice stuff from crossfilter. Thanks, I'll copy paste the details from #584 and close

Comment: I wonder if a better path isn't to keep crossfilter, but provide sensible defaults (eg group() is often a reduceCount (return +1)... I'll experiment a bit.

Comment: Yes you can also use crossfilter and reduce by some unique key, e.g. the row index. We should spell this out somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the "normal" way is to define data(), but as this function is already defined internally from some charts, it doesn't work that well:

in http://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584 
Details: the following charts use .data() internally:

- Stack Mixin (thus Line and Bar) - filters and then does stack d3.layout.stack on the data Cap Mixin (thus Pie and Row) - optionally limits the number of bins, sorts the groups using the ordering, and optionally creates the "others" bin
- Number Chart - looks to see if the group has a value() function (e.g. it's a group-all). Otherwise, takes the top value. Runs the valueAccessor on the result (!!!)
- Box Plot - adds a mapping function to the data. Filters out values (which are themselves arrays) that are of length 0.

Comment: Thanks. Please accept your answer when the system allows it. I think `.data` can be made to work, but it's some work. Right now I think you could use [fake groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted) but it's some work on your side. If you have a better idea, please raise an issue or post to the user group.